# Filter for reverse relation that points to self in Q object

Tags: django

I want to filter the lookup in a reverse Foreignkey field to fields that do not have any reverse references. This is easily done:

```
class MyBaseClass(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=4)

def block_filter():
    return {'myreferenceclass__isnull': True} 

class MyReferenceClass(models.Model):
    mybase= models.ForeignKey(MyBaseClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        limit_choices_to = block_filter)
```

That works well if not for that if I want to update an instance of the MyReferenceClass I cannot save it (in the admin) as the referred object is not in the lookup. So the field is empty though it has already a value in the database.

Now I want to use a Q object that filters is_null=True plus the entry that refers to self. However, I am stuck with the latter. Can I do this in the Q object?

Comment: I think you should better get rid of `limit_choices_to` at all, and modify your [AdminForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) to achieve the desired behavior.